# Serialization of an OGRE scene

Tags: serialization, ogre, scene

What are current most popular solutions for saving OGRE scene in a file? I found the DotScene one, but the last commit there was 4 years ago so it may be quite outdated.
Are there other plugins or mods to save and load OGRE scenes?

Comment: Unfortunately OGRE doesn't provide anything for the serialization of a scene. A third alternative to what I said [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13563944/how-to-create-a-mesh-file-with-ogre?answertab=votes#tab-top): think to switch to the OGRE BSP scene manager, but as said [here](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=SceneManagersFAQ#BSP_Scene_Manager) is pretty _deprecated_.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why there is no dedicated official scene serialization is, that this is a highly application specific task and got next to nothing to do with Ogre3D itself. For basic prototypes DotScene is the way to go, but many projects will later extend that XML structure to accommodate their own needs which is no difficult task.

You might also want to have a look at [Ogitor](http://www.ogitor.org/) which is a growing WYSIWYG editor based on Ogre with DotScene support as well as its own format (make sure to either grab a dev build or build it yourself as our last official stable version 0.4 is rather outdated, but we haven't gotten around to do the 0.5 release just yet).